# Use INSERT and variable in SQL Lite

Tags: sqlite

I am noob in SqlLite, I have the following situation, I have three tables: `Table1`, `Table2` and `Table3`

```
Table1 has ID (primary key auto increment) INTEGER, title TEXT
Table2 has ID (primary key auto increment) INTEGER, Table1_ID INTEGER
Table3 has ID (primary key auto increment) INTEGER, Table2_ID INTEGER
```

Only way to use variable to store latest added id in table, is to create a temporary table

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS _Variables(Table1ID INTEGER, Table2ID INTEGER, Table3ID INTEGER);
```

Add values in `Table1`

```
INSERT INTO Table1 ( ... ) VALUES ( ... )

INSERT INTO _Variables(Table1ID, Table2ID, Table3ID) VALUES (last_insert_rowid(), -1, -1);
```

Add values in `Table2`

```
INSERT INTO Table2 ( ... ) VALUES ( ... );

UPDATE _Variables SET Table2ID = last_insert_rowid();
```

Now I want to latest id from Table1 and Table2 into `Table3`

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (...) VALUES ( @idTbl1, @idTbl2);
```

I don't know here what is a good approach for this ?

Comment: What language are you using to access SQLite?

Comment: No language, I use sql lite studio

Answer (score 0):

You could look up each value with a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO Table3 VALUES((SELECT Table1ID FROM _Variables),
                          (SELECT Table2ID FROM _Variables));
```

But if all these values are in the same row of the same table, you can use a single query:

```
INSERT INTO Table3
SELECT Table1ID, Table2ID
FROM _Variables;
```